# Android Layouts?

Tags: android-layout

relative layout and linear layout are known as what?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to ask better questions and get better answers. Your question is of a really low quality, please edit it!

Answer (score 0):

Relative layout and linear layout are known as ViewGroup.